# Files in Python 3

Tags: python, file

I have the following code:

```
# Read files

file = open("lightning_data.txt",'r')
filelen=len(file.read())
print('file length is', filelen)
file.close()


file = open("lightning_data.txt",'w')


if filelen<3:
    file.write('0.90 \n1.68 \n10.752 \n8.54892')
    print('written to file')

file.close()
```

When i run it, i see the following:

```
file length is 0
written to file
```

The file has been created and filled with "0.90 \n1.68 \n10.752 \n8.54892"

If i run it again, the output is:

```
file length is 27
```

And the file becomes empty! Why?

***Solved***

Comment: Because, `len('0.90 \n1.68 \n10.752 \n8.54892')` is ...

Comment: The file is empty because `filelen == 27`, which is `< 3` nothing is wrriten, but the file handle has already been opened to write, creating an empty file- what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the command

```
file = open("lightning_data.txt",'w')
```

will truncate the file each time you open it. Because of this, when you ran the second time, it truncates the elements inside and you end up with an empty file. You can change this line to

```
file = open("lightning_data.txt",'a')
```

and then the contents will not be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Because the program did what you told it to:

- Open the file for writing
- Only write to the file (and print about doing so) if its current length (measured in bytes) is less than 3
- Close the file either way

Comment: A (not-necessarily-obvious-to-newcomers) key point -- opening for writing will truncate the file. The minute it's opened that way, its length becomes 0 until something is written to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file the second time to write with the mode 'w' you said to overwrite what is in the file and since you don't write anything unless filelen is less than 3 nothing is written therefore you get an empty file. The file mode you are looking for might be 'a'